# Isn't MongoDB actually storing plaintext passwords?

Tags: authentication, mongodb

According to the documentation at
http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/implement-authentication-in-driver/:

> The driver then runs the authenticate command for the database on which to authenticate.
> The authenticate command has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> db.runCommand( { authenticate : 1, user : <username>, nonce : <nonce>, key : <digest> }
> ```
>
> `<username>` is a username in the database’s system.users collection.
>
> `<nonce>` is the nonce returned from a previous getnonce step.
>
> `<digest>` is the hex encoding of an *MD5 message digest*.
>
> The *MD5 message digest* is the MD5 hash of the concatenation of `<nonce>`, `<username>`, `<password_digest>`.
>
> The `<password_digest>` is the value in the `pwd` field associated with the `<username>` in the database's `system.users` collection.  The `pwd` is the hex encoding of `MD5( <username> + ":mongo:" + <password_text> )`.

This means that the hashing is actually done client-side, as the driver is part of the client for the database connection.  In order to authenticate, the client does not need to demonstrate knowledge of the password but of the stored hash.  So, the real password is the stored hash, which just happens to have been generated through hashing something.  That real password is stored in plaintext in the `pwd` field of `system.users`.

Am I reading that wrong?  Is there a way to secure this authentication?

Answer (score 4):

In a sense, that can be considered correct.

From what I understood from the MongoDB documentation, the `db.addUser()` expects one to pass in an already hashed password. This is clearly seen from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/) of the function, where the expected data type of the `pwd` field is `hash`.

I read this as MongoDB expecting the system to perform the hashing prior to registration or authentication of users in the database. This makes sense when you consider that the MongoDB user most likely isn't going to be typing the password hash by hand. The use case for these user accounts are as authentication credentials for applications so the passwords are most certainly going to be stored in a configuration file somewhere.

The [enterprise version](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise) of MongoDB supports the use of Kerberos for authentication. The steps to setup Kerberos can be found in the [documentations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-kerberos-authentication/) as well. If you are really worried about this as a security factor, you should look into setting up Kerberos.

Comment: Minor nitpick. Kerberos is only supported in the enterprise (i.e. paid) version of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not store passwords in plaintext.  As of MongoDB 3.0, Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM) is the default authentication mechanism for MongoDB.  Scram supports both SCRAM-SHA-1 and SCRAM-SHA-256 hashing mechanisms.

Having said that, when interfacing with a database via driver, these often accept a hashed password so that it is not transmitted to and from the database in plaintext form.  This imposes additional responsibility on the developer because he/she has to perform the hashing at their end using the same algorithm as is employed within the DB server.  Luckily, these are readily available for just about any programming language.

Querying the system.users collection will return a document similar to this:

```
{
  "_id": "admin.123",
  "user": "123",
  "db": "admin",
  "credentials": {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1": {
      "iterationCount": 10000,
      "salt": "f9SdPCCcBOwk71/xDkj6Sw==",
      "storedKey": "83mNhTYctOdlYsL1sbnfpiA0uxw=",
      "serverKey": "09H9aEKKufaoCDxqUkHntx6EqrE="
    }
  },
  "roles": []
}
```

You can delve into the users and other collections with a good DB admin tool such as [Navicat for MongoDB](https://navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mongodb).  It lets you view documents in three formats: Tree, JSON, and grid:

[image: Navicat Views]

Hope that answers your question.

rob